# Apache-Camel file move recursive to same subdirectory

Tags: apache-camel

I have currently a camel route which process a zip file and afterwards move it to a storage folder.

```
from(
    file://importDir?recursive=true&preMove=processing&move=storage&moveFailed=error&include=.*\\.zip$
).bean(bean, "process")
```

In the actual *import*-Directory are subdirectories with the zip files. I would like to have the same subdirectories in the *storage*-directory and probably in the *processing*-directory too.
Any idea if i can do this with the route and file-language expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set `recursive=true` you can't set `move=storage` since this would cause a loop.

**For example:**

1. file.zip is placed to `/importDir/some-folder/`
2. File consumer reads the file and sends it for processors
3. After processing the original file is stored to `/importDir/some-folder/storage/`
4. File consumer recursively finds the file.zip from `/importDir/some-folder/storage/`
5. After processing places it again put to `/importDir/some-folder/storage/storage/`
6. repeats indefinitely

Now what you can do instead is set `move=.storage` which would place the file in above example to `/importDir/some-folder/.storage/` which would be ignored by the file consumer endpoint.

Even cleaner solution would be to store the processed files outside `/importDir/` by using for example `move=/somepath/storage/${file:name}`. More about this in [camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/file-component.html#_fine_grained_control_over_move_and_premove_option)

With ${file:name} the directory structure should stay the same in both storage and importDir.

Comment: I am also using `preMove=processing` which should prevent the said loop-problem.

Comment: My understanding is that `preMove` just stores it to `/importDir/some-folder/processing/` which wont prevent the loop problem with `recursive=true` since processing is still under the `/importDir/` folder. The folder name needs to have dot in it for Camel to ignore the directory or outside the `/importDir/` folder using simple and file language.